# Why is this contour integral undefined?

Tags: contour-integration

Define the following contours:
[image: contours]

I have a question which requires me to, if possible, compute the contour integral
$$
\int_{\gamma + \delta + \epsilon} \cos (z) dz
$$
However, in the mark scheme it says that this integral is undefined (with no explanation as to why).

Could anyone please explain to me why this integral is undefined?

Comment: Should it be $\gamma+\delta-\epsilon$? I notice that $\epsilon$ runs in the wrong direction.